# Failed to use time() wrapper of Summary in Promutheus

Tags: python-3.x, prometheus

I encounter an error when using `Summary.time()` decorator.

```
REQUEST_TIMER = Summary('aes_request_processing_timer', 'Time spent processing requests', ['time'])
class HallyServiceHandler(hally_service_pb2_grpc.HallyServicer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HallyServiceHandler, self).__init__()
        return

    @REQUEST_TIMER.time()
    def ProcessStas(self, request, context):
        return hally_service_pb2.StasResponse()
```

When I start the server

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100))

health_pb2_grpc.add_HealthServicer_to_server(health_handler.Health(), server)

hally_service_pb2_grpc.add_HallyServicer_to_server(
    hally_service_handler.HallyServiceHandler(), server
)

server.add_insecure_port('[::]:8080')
server.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

I failed to start the server.

```
    @REQUEST_TIMER.time()
AttributeError: '_LabelWrapper' object has no attribute 'time'
```

The usage is similar with the [Docs](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python).

**Environment**

- python 3.6.0
- prometheus_client: 0.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REQUEST_TIMER` has a label `time` which you aren't providing. As you don't actually need that label, remove the `, ['time']` from your metric definition.

Also you should mention the unit of a metric like this and `timer` is redundant, so:

```
REQUEST_TIMER = Summary('aes_request_processing_duration_seconds', 'Time spent processing requests')
```